# Picture Shuffle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have bootstrap and I have thumbnails set up to display a set of pictures. I want the thumbnails to stay put and not move. But I want the pictures to change inside the thumbnails and have the size of the image adjust to the thumbnail that it is in.

I want the thumbnails to stay in one spot and maintain size.

I want the pictures to shuffle in between the different thumbnails and adjust it's size to match the thumbnail it is in.

I currently have this script that shuffles the thumbnails around the page: (What I don't want)

```
(function($){

    $.fn.shuffle = function() {

        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
           });

        this.each(function(i){
            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        });

        return $(shuffled);

    };

})(jQuery);

$(function(){
$('ul#list li').shuffle();
})
```

The thumbnails markup looks like the following.

```
<ul class="thumbnails" id="list">
    <li class="span4">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/360x270" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span3">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/160x120" alt="">
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What could I change on the script that shuffles the thumbnails that would make it just shuffle the images and make those images adjust to the thumbnail it is located in? I have tried so much to get this. I hope I am making the question clear enough on what I am wanting.

Comment: @Antony what did you change?

Comment: Removed white spaces (indenting the codes), and added a tag.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Just seeing.

Comment: @user2371301 will you be able to give predefined height and width for the image tags like `<img src="http://placehold.it/260x120" alt="" height="120" width="260">`

Answer (score 0):

Give height and width properties to the `img` elements like

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/360x270" alt="" width="360" height="270"/>
```

Then

```
(function($){

    //+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
    //@ http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle [v1.0]
    function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
    };

    $.fn.shuffle = function() {

        var srcs =  this.find('img').map(function(i, el){
            return el.src;
        });
        shuffle(srcs)

        return this.each(function(i){
            $(this).find('img').attr('src', srcs[i]);
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$(function(){
    $('ul#list li').shuffle();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MkMHu/)

Comment: The thumbnails are still moving.

Comment: @user2371301 what do you mean by moving

Comment: Yeah that isn't what I am wanting. Forget it, I'm done. I'm dropping the idea. I want the thumbnails to maintain size and position. Just make the pictures move and make the pictures adjust to the size of the thumbnail. THE THUMBNAILS NEED TO STAY IN ONE 1 SPOT.

Comment: BTW: You add bootstrap css and js into that fiddle. It won't work.

Comment: @user2371301 if you are using bootstrap change the def to `<img src="http://placehold.it/360x270" alt="" style="width: 360px; height: 270px"/>` as in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MkMHu/5/